# Swift - Assign newValue to an Object

Tags: ios, swift

I know that probably is a very simple question, however I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why is not working, and still doesn't make sense for me, so I need help.

I am learning iOS, I came from Android where I am used to work with objects.
I want to do something similar that I have been doing with Android(maybe this is the problem).

I have created an object with the methods get and set.

```
private var _token: String!

var error: String {
    get {
        guard self._error != nil else { return "" }
        return _error
    }
    set {
        self._token = newValue
    }
}
```

When I want to manipulate this object, is when I am having the problem.

```
let objectCreated = ObjectCreated()
guard let errorReceived = (xml["Whatever"]["Whatever"].element?.text) else { return }

print(errorReceived)
objectCreated.error = errorReceived
print(objectCreated.error)
```

The first print is printing the correct String, but the second is printing "". So the set method is not doing his job.

Comment: You are *setting* `_token`. and *getting* `error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it supposed to be

```
...
guard self._token != nil else { return "" }
    return _token
...
```

This can be simplified with the nil-coalescing operator

```
var error: String {
    get {
        return self._token ?? ""
    }
    set {
        self._token = newValue
    }
}
```

Note: Variable names with leading underscores are unusual in Swift.

Comment: Probably, `return _self.token` should be `return self._token` in `get`.

Comment: @pacification Of course, thanks. I'm unfamiliar with underscores in variable names 

Answer (score 1):

```
private var _error: String!

var error: String {
    get {
        guard self._error != nil else { return "" }
        return _error
    }
    set {
        self._error = newValue
    }
}
```

`self._token = newValue >>>>  self._error` = newValue